# high sierra on MBP2010 microphone and card reader not working anymore

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, microphone, sd-card

I have recently upgraded my MBP mid2010 to HighSierra and I am struggling to get the card reader and microphone to work. I can see them in the system report but the mic isn't working and the card reader doesn't mount any cards.

I am using the new apple file system, I have the best specs I was able to get, 8GB of RAM, 256GB SSD so it's running nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The card reader issue can be solved with starting "Image Capture.app" while inserting the card. The reference for this is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BA9jcj9Wrs).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  How does this address the microphone issue also asked by the OP?

Comment: I understand the authors question as two different ones. My solution solves one of them.